# Looking for a PHP solution to "export" svn directory in a server that does not have SVN installed

Tags: php, svn

I guess this question was asked in one way or another, but I'm looking for a more specific way of doing it, and I haven't found a `clean` solution to do so.

Anyway, I have a hosted SVN solution (using beanstalkapp.com), I'm using it to version changes in my main site.

The server the site is hosted on, does not have SVN installed, so I need to use other tools (PHP+SVN, FTP, SSH, etc') to update the files on the server.

What I'm looking for is a PHP script/library that will allow me to:

1. Commit certain files to the SVN (mainly Database).
2. Update files on the server with newer files from the SVN. - I'd rather not have .svn files on my server if it's possible.
3. if 2. is impossible or impracticle, I can also delete the entire directory, and overright new files.
4. Another option could be to use a dedicated directory for the SVN files, and from there copy the file (without .svn) to the production directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .svn directories will still be needed in order to update your working copy. If your server has PEAR installed (or you could make PEAR work in some way), you could try SVN PECL extension: http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/ref.svn.php. With some Googling, you could also have found http://code.google.com/p/phpsvnclient/, which seems to be an all-PHP solution without any PEAR dependencies.